# assistance with issues when creating a unit conversion app in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I'm coding this unit conversion app for my app dev class. I have to use a spinner and I have to display TextView values to the left of the numeric i/o values that align with the selection made in the spinner. (IE User selects "Miles to Kilometers" in the spinner, Underneath the spinner I have 4 boxes, 3 TextView 1 EditText. The EditText is obviously for the user to input their Miles value and one TextView is for the output of Kilometers after ratios are used to convert. My question is: How do I use the other two TextView boxes to display Miles in one and Kilometers in the other respectively and for all other remaining conversion options via the spinner) I know the code is incomplete at the moment but I am having a hard time thinking a way around displaying those text values. And to add an extension onto that question - Is it possible to call each individual item and assign that item the appropriate ratio. (IE- 
    outputResult = resultMiles
    outputresult = resultKilometers??

Sorry if that question is vague I'm having trouble coming up with the right words to phrase it correctly.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.corey.unitconversionappbycoreywhitlow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner spinnerConversions;
    TextView conversionFrom, conversionTo, outputResult;
    EditText userInput;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        conversionFrom = findViewById(R.id.fromValue);
        conversionTo = findViewById(R.id.toValue);
        outputResult = findViewById(R.id.resultOutput);
        userInput = findViewById(R.id.numInput);





        spinnerConversions = findViewById(R.id.conversionSpinner);
        spinnerConversions.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Miles to Kilometers");
        list.add("Kilometers to Miles");
        list.add("Inches to Centimeters");
        list.add("Centimeters to Inches");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
        spinnerConversions.setAdapter(adapter);







    }

    public void onClick(View view){

        int listIndex = spinnerConversions.getSelectedItemPosition();
        float inputValues = Float.parseFloat(userInput.getText().toString());




        outputResult.setText(result+"");
    }





    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){}

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){}
}
```

Comment: This post is very large please ask your question as quick as you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is my answer based on the way I understood your question**

This is my first time using split(), this however should work.

```
String convType = (get the current conversion type from adapter);
String[] units = convType.split("to");
String convFrom = units[0].trim();
String convTo = units[1].trim();
//display the strings normally into your TextView...
```

**EDIT:**

This is the convertion type (Add this to onItemSelected):

```
String convType = list.get(position);
```

And create the **list** under **EditText userInput**, not in **onCreate**.

Comment: What is the conversion type? I have an adapter set as "adapter". Would it be:
    String conversionType = (list, adapter);

?

Comment: conversion type is the string you are using in the adapter, EX: "Miles to Kilometers"

Comment: What do you mean to create the list under EditText userInput? I put it there and it says 'add' cannot be resolved. So I added 

    String conversionType = list.get(0);
        String[] units = conversionType.split("to");
        String convFrom = units[0].trim();
        String convTo = units[1].trim();


and I put it underneath spinnerConversions.setAdapter(adapter);
instead of onClick which I deleted.

Comment: Also - how would I reference convFrom and convTo into an actual output. Right now they’re being unused?